# run same cypress test specs for multiple domain

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing

I am trying to test the same logic hosted on different domains by using multiple `it` functions, not ONLY one. It works when I use one but fails when using multiple.

Does anyone have any suggestions based on experience on how to approach this?

My code:

```
const domains = require("../fixtures/domains.js")
context(`description here`, function () {
  domains.urls.forEach(domain => {
    before(function () {
      cy.server()
      
    })
    after(function () {
      cy.clearCookie("")
    })
```

And then want to have multiple it function per case.

```
it('should ', function () {
            //do something
          });

it('should ', function () {
            //do something
          });

it('should ', function () {
            do something
          });
```

Comment: Hello, what error do you get? II see you are trying to access different URLs from different tests, so https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages.html#cy-visit-failed-because-you-are-attempting-to-visit-a-different-origin-domain shouldn't apply. Please post the error message, thanks.

Comment: What version of Cypress are you using?